# Dhtmlx Gantt worked at XAMPP but not VPS server

Tags: javascript, laravel, gantt-chart, dhtmlx

I'm using dhtmlx Gantt in Laravel.

I use this dhtmlx gantt script:

https://github.com/Ojsholly/gantt_chart

It perfectly worked at XAMPP. However I put my VPS server then I got this error:

```
Failed to load the data from 
https://xxxxxxxxxxxx/api/data?dhxr160868036091=1
server returns 404
```

I thought the cause is Node.js wasn't installed. I installed it but I still have same error.

My Node. js version is v14.15.3

My Blade file's js part is this

```
 <script src="https://cdn.dhtmlx.com/gantt/edge/dhtmlxgantt.js"></script>    
 <link href="https://cdn.dhtmlx.com/gantt/edge/dhtmlxgantt.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js shouldn't be related to that issue. It seems that you need to change the URL that you use to load tasks.

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I appreciate that. Could you teach me where to change please?

Comment: The URL should be changed here:

https://github.com/Ojsholly/gantt_chart/blob/master/resources/views/gantt.blade.php#L29

But I cannot suggest what kind of value you need to put there.

Comment: I'm sorry to late reply. And Thank you very much for answer.